# Update form not work after using custom clean method

Tags: django, forms, view

My model form:

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%m/%d/%Y"))
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude =('user',)

    def clean(self):
        user = get_user(self.request)
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        birth_date = self.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
        if Person.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
            self.add_error('name', "You already submitted data")
        elif Person.objects.filter(name=name, birth_date=birth_date).exists():
            self.add_error('name', "Person with this Name and Birth date already exists.")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        person = super().save(commit=False)
        if not person.pk:
            person.user = get_user(self.request)
        if commit:
            person.save()
            self.save_m2m()
        return person
```

my views:

```
class PersonCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
    model = Person
    success_url = '/person/'
    form_class = MemberForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.request = self.request
        return form


class PersonUpdate(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
    model = Person
    success_url = '/person/'
    form_class = MemberForm
```

My MemberForm worked fine when I create a person. It also give validation errors in the form when user is not unique and user name and birth date are combinedly not unique. But when I tried to update the saved form it gives error and say: "'MemberForm' object has no attribute 'request'"

If I use

```
 def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.request = self.request
        return form
```

in UpdateView it raises my custom validation errors like CreateForm. Since  the same person already in the database. Could anyone suggest me the way how do I fix the Updateform so that it correctly update my existing data.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I solved it using if self.instance.id: block in my clean method. I will post my working code very soon.

Answer (score 1):

The working code is:

```
def clean(self):
    user = get_user(self.request)
    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
    birth_date = self.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
    if self.instance.id:
        if Person.objects.filter(user=user).exclude(id=self.instance.id).exists():
            self.add_error('name', "You already submitted data")
        elif Person.objects.filter(name=name, birth_date=birth_date).exclude(id=self.instance.id).exists():
            self.add_error('name', "Person with this Name and Birth date already exists.")
    else:
        if Person.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
            self.add_error('name', "You already submitted data")
        elif Person.objects.filter(name=name, birth_date=birth_date).exists():
            self.add_error('name', "Person with this Name and Birth date already exists.")
    return self.cleaned_data
```

and in views:

```
class PersonUpdate(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
    model = Person
    success_url = '/person/'
    form_class = MemberForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.request = self.request
        return form
```